# Dapper: How to get value from DapperRow if column name is "count(*)"?

Tags: dapper

I have a dynamic result from [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) query that contains records like this:

```
{DapperRow, billing_currency_code = 'USD', count(*) = '6'}
```

I'm able to access 'USD' by using `rowVariable.billing_currency_code`

To get '6' value I tried `rowVariable["count(*)"]` and `rowVariable.kv["count(*)"]` and unfortunately nothing works...

I can't change the `count(*)` column name in my case

How to get the '6' value from the `rowVariable` of type [DapperRow](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/451d50ba5ea3f86d48078e00d29f336199a18d4c/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs#L2026) in such case?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but can't you use an alias in the query so you don't have 'count(*)', but a readable name instead? If you provide the query, I might be able to help.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't add an alias or edit the query in any other way.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If the column name *genuinely is* `"count(*)"`, then you can cast the row to a dictionary:

```
var data = (IDictionary<string,object>)row;
object value = data["count(*)"];
```

For that to work (at least, in SQL Server), your query would need to be something like:

```
select count(*) as [count(*)]
```

However, in most cases the column *doesn't have a name*, in which case: fix your query ;p

Actually, I'd probably say fix your query *anyway*; the following would be much easier to work with:

```
select count(*) as [Count]
```

Comment: I can't change the query, but casting to IDictionary helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Suppose Your Data as below

```
var Details={DapperRow, billing_currency_code = 'USD', count(*) = '6'}
```

as The columns is coming dynamically

```
var firstRow= Details.FirstOrDefault();
```

To get the heading columns of the data

```
var Heading= ((IDictionary<string, object>)firstRow).Keys.ToArray();
```

To get the value of the data by using key

```
var details = ((IDictionary<string, object>)firstRow);
var vallues= details[Heading[0]];
```

Comment: Nicely explained Example for beginners.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I was trying to get the properties of a dynamic (that was a DapperRow) and GetType().GetProperties() wasn't empty and TypeDescriptor.GetProperties() was returning double the values.